# Eloquent/Laravel: Nested lazy eager loading, but return multiple model's relations

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

Apologies if the title does not make much sense, but here's what I've got and what I'd like to achieve.

There's a restaurant's menu, which is structured like this:

```
Restaurant
|- category 1
   |- subcategory 1
   |- subcategory 2
      |- item 1
         * price levels:
         |- price level 1
         |- price level 2
         * modifiers groups:
         |- group 1
            |- modifier 1
            |- modifier 2
```

The goal is to write the most efficient way (in terms of database queries) to get the entire menu (served as JSON via API), but there's a catch: I need both price levels AND modifiers for each item.

The most efficient way that I came up with is:

Part 1: chain all the way up to item's modifiers (because they're more nested than price levels):

```
$this->restaurant->load('categories.subcategories.items.modifier_groups_enabled.modifiers_enabled');
```

Part 2:
Before starting the loop through categories/subcategories/items, I "manually" get all price levels that belong to all items in a restaurant, then I put them into an array, grouped by item's id. Then, while looping through the menu, I just grab the `$price_levels[$item->id]` as an array of item's price levels.

With nothing cached, the entire request is complete in 7 queries, which is OK, but the 'dirty' way of preparing price levels is bothering me a bit :)

If I cut the nested eager loading up to items only, then get each item's price levels and modifiers (`$item->load[...]`), database queries pile up since each item runs its own ones to get price levels and modifier groups/modifiers.

So, the question is: Can `$this->restaurant->load('...')` be written in such a way that it also returns all items' price levels AND modifiers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, the question is: Can $this->restaurant->load('...') be written in such a way that it also returns all items' price levels AND modifiers?

Of course, just specify price levels the same way as modifier groups:

```
$this->restaurant->load(
    'categories.subcategories.items.modifier_groups_enabled.modifiers_enabled',
    'categories.subcategories.items.price_levels'
);
```

Comment: Ouch, I've never thought about that (haven't seen a similar example either). Big thanks, it's a lot more elegant this way, and even slightly faster than what I've had.

Comment: The first example under [Lazy Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading) shows the loading of two relationships. You're pretty much doing the same, you're just loading two relationships of a nested relationship, so your initial `categories.subcategories.items` will be the same for both.

Comment: Yep, I just didn't think I'd work properly (or at all) with nested relationships and I didn't even try to see if it'd throw an error... just dismissed it as not possible (and tried many other crazy stuff instead). Need to work on abandoning that approach :)